# Proof that an infinite set stays infinite after subtraction of one element (under Dedekind's infinity defintion)

Tags: elementary-set-theory

After Dedekind, M is an infinite set if N $\subset$ M and f: M $\to$ N bijective. How do you prove that M - {b} (= taking one element b away from M) is infinite as well, just using this definition and functions? Is it possible? (Please make it as simple & step-by-step as you can since I am not a pro.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to clarify, $M$ is Dedekind infinite if there exist a proper subset $N$ of $M$ such that there is a bijection $f:M\to N$.

Claim 1: Any superset of a Dedekind infinite set is also Dedekind infinite.

Say $A$ is Dedekind infinite and $B$ a superset of $A$. Let $C$ be a proper subset of $A$ and $f:A\to C$ a bijection. Then, $f$ extends to a bijection $g:B\to C\cup (B\backslash A)$ which is the identity on $B\backslash A$ and $f$ on $A$. Hence $B$ is Dedekind infinite.

Claim 2: Dedekind infiniteness is preserved by bijection i.e. if there is a bijection between sets $A$ and $B$ and $A$ is Dedekind infintie then so is $B$.

Suppose $M$ is Dedekind infinite, $N$ a proper subset of $M$ and $f :M\to N$ is a bijection. By Claim 2, $N$ is Dedekind infinite.

As $N$ is a proper subset of $M$, $N$ is a subset of $M\backslash\{m\}$ for some $m\in M$.  By Claim 1, as $M\backslash \{m\}$ is a superset of $N$, $M\backslash \{m\}$ is also Dedekind infinite. Finally, for any $b\in M$ there is a clear choice bijection from $M\backslash \{m\}$ to $M\backslash \{b\}$ and so $M\backslash \{b\}$ is Dedekind infinite as desired.

Comment: I can edit to prove either claim if needed.

Comment: Can u prove it without your two claims too?

Comment: I would guess any reasonable step by step solution would need these claims implicitly at least.

Comment: Ok, could u prove claim 1?

Comment: See the edits above.

Comment: I have problems with your proof - using claim 1 - that a set stays infinite even if you take away one element. Claim 1 - and I proved that meanwhile for myself - says that any superset of a dedekind-infinite set is also dedekind-infinite. But in your proof M\{m} is just a superset of N and N is not necessarily dedekind-infinite. Only M was assumed dedekind-infinite. Can u somehow rescue the proof?

Comment: $N$ is dedekind infinite as it is in bijection with $M$. Claim 2 is used for this. To be explicit $f(N)$ is the proper subset of $N$ that $N$ is in bijection with.